# How can I prevent the function from beeing executed immediately?

Tags: javascript, html

I want to define an onclick action, but it's executing it's self after this line:

```
document.getElementById("rollDiceAction").onclick = rollDiceSpecial();
```

What can I do?

Comment: don't include the `()`, just assign the function name to onclick.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To reference a function, just say its name:

```
x = foo;  // Set x equal to the function foo
```

To invoke it put parenthesis after its name:

```
x = foo(); // Invoke foo and set x equal to the result
```

Just get rid of the parenthesis at the end of your line to associate the `rollDiceSpecial` function with the `onclick` property.

```
 document.getElementById("rollDiceAction").onclick = rollDiceSpecial;
```

Comment: @Progaros  You're welcome. Don't forget to mark as the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the parentheses:

```
document.getElementById("rollDiceAction").onclick = rollDiceSpecial;
```

You should really be using `addEventListener`, though -- assigning to the element's `onclick` attribute is a bit old-school, and limits you to one event handler per element.

```
document.getElementById("rollDiceAction").addEventListener("click", rollDiceSpecial);
```